# Get AJAX to Manipulate on Symfony Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, controller, symfony

I am using Symfony 3, and I have this code on my twig file:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "{{ path('route-action-save') }}",
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {"endDate":$("#enddatepicker").val(),   
                 "startDate":$("#startdatepicker").val(),  
                 "array_tenant_id": array_tenant_id},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert($("#enddatepicker").val());
            }

        })
```

And I have this as my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/route/action/save", name="route-action-save")
 * @Method({"POST"})
*/
public function checkBoxAction(Request $request){


    $arrayTenantID = $request->request->get('array_tenant_id');
    return $this->render('default/validation.html.twig', array('nameID' => $arrayTenantID));
}
```

When I try to render it to validation.html.twig, it shows NULL.
is there anything I am missing to see the values?

My goal is to get array_tenant_id, startDate, and endDate and use those values to query on the database.

However, getting it from Ajax to my controller is my main priority, and being able to render it on validation.html.twig

Thank you,

Comment: Are you trying to get json response from checkBoxAction?
because "dataType" indicate "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server."

Comment: right up in the function try :
`dump($request->request);`
and look if you have the values in there . If not your problem is from Jquery.